# setOnItemClickListener doesn't work with Android Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

setOnItemClickListener doesn't work with android Spinner. Here is my code:

```
supplier.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String msupplier=supplier.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    Log.e("Selected item : ",msupplier);

                }
            });
```

Comment: can you provide some more code of that activity?

Comment: please add your adapter code and your spinner item's xml to the question

Answer (score 51, accepted):

setOnItemClickListener will not work with android spinner.Alternatively, try using this method:

> setOnItemSelectedListener

Change your code like this:

```
supplier.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String msupplier=supplier.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Log.e("Selected item : ",msupplier);
}

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Problem with spinner is that you only get notified if you changed the selected item, and never if you clicked on the same item, thus the need for a itemClicked event.

Answer (score 6):

`OnItemSelectedListener()` serves a different purpose than a click listener. Most importantly, it doesn't fire if you click on the currently selected item again. In some cases this might not be a problem but in other cases, it might well be. So the real answer is not to tell people to use a different and probably unsuitable listener but to solve the original problem. :-)

Fortunately, we can place the click listener on the adapter instead:

```
public class SpinnerClickAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
  protected OnItemClickListener listener;

  public SpinnerClickAdapter(Context context, ..., OnItemClickListener listener) {
    super();

    this.listener = listener;
  }

  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, false);

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (listener != null)
          listener.onItemClick((AdapterView<?>) parent, v, position, getItemId(position));
      }
    });


    // ...

    return convertView;
  }
}
```

and then we can use it as usual, with the only difference of not setting it on the spinner but on the adapter instead:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourspinner);
SpinnerClickAdapter spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerClickAdapter(context, ..., new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO
  }
});
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: hi, nice work, but how to collapse spinner after item selection?

Comment: @ErfanEghterafi check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18076520/8781554).

Answer (score 5):

**1.** I think you should check your xml file which contains the spinner. Make sure haven't set `android:clickable = "false"`.

**2.** please check your spinner adapter and make sure in your `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method, you haven't set any widget click callback event such as `Button`,`Imageview`,`TextView`

Answer (score 4):

I may be going off course, but thought to suggest you to use `OnItemSelectedListener` which is broader than `OnItemClickListener` for Spinners:

```
supplier.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
        //do something here
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        //optionally do something here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getItemAtPosition:

```
supplier.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
supplier.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

i have faced this issues. setOnItemClickListener will not works with spinner. My solution is as following:

```
mSpinnerYears.setAdapter(adapter);
    mSpinnerYears.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Logger.d(new StringBuilder(2).append("TAG:").append(TAG).toString(),
                    new StringBuilder(3).append("click pos = ").append(position).append(
                            mSpinnerYears.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()).toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `supplier` in your code means `spinner`, do Replace this line

```
 String msupplier=supplier.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

with the below line:

```
 String msupplier= supplier.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```