# How to hide spinner dropdown android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to hide spinner prompt popup on outside click. If prompt popup is open and user press home key activity will minimize so when user again open application that prompt popup should disappear.
Is there any way to achieve this. 
Thank You

Edit:-- Prompt popup is not customized. So I can't hide them in `onPause` or `onResume` methods.

Comment: Blind guess (so it not goes as answer): wouldn't taking focus from this view on `onResume()` solve the issue?

Comment: u need use onStart() or onResume() method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well its a little complicated than I thought.

I am adding the step by step details here. Try to follow it. I was able to achieve this in api level 10.

**And this solution assumes that you are supposed to close the prompt dialog programatically when the user clicks on Home Button or If you had to move to next activity without user interaction**

The first step is to create a Custom Spinner by extending Spinner Class. 
Let's say, I have created a class called **CustomSpinner** in the package **com.bts.sampleapp**

My CustomSpinner class looks like this,

```
package com.bts.sampleapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner{
        Context context=null;

        public CustomSpinner(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context=context;
        }

        public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }
    }
```

Now in your Xml file, replace Spinner element by this custom spinner,

```
        <com.bts.sampleapp.CustomSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The next step is to initialize and set adapter to this spinner in your Activity class,

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CustomSpinner spin=null;
    spin=(CustomSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);
    spin.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter); //you can set your adapter here.
}
```

The final step is to close the dialog when the user clicks on HomeButton or When the Activity moves to background. To do this, we override the onPause() like this,

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i("Life Cycle", "onPause");
        spin.onDetachedFromWindow();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Now within the onPause() call the method `spin.onDetachedFromWindow();` which does the job of closing the prompt dialog for you.

**Also calling `spin.onDetachedFromWindow();` from anywhere within the Acitivity should close the Spinner prompt dialog if it is open.**

Comment: It's worked...
One more thing can we select same item twice in spinner.. I think we need to modify customspinner class for that?

Comment: you mean like a multiple selection? I am not sure. I have not tried it. Sorry for that..

Comment: Not multiple selection suppose your spinner has 5 items you selected item 2 then again if you select item 2 spinner will not fire onItemSelection method

Comment: THANK YOU. This is only method I found that works. I'm using a voice interface to select the spinner item and needed it to close when the words spoken matched an item in the list.

Comment: how can i detect whether spinner popup is dismissed( by item select or touches outside of popup)...???

Answer (score 23):

Based on Andro's answer, you may prefer reflection to be able to call the protected method onDetachedFromWindow. Then you don't have to subclass Spinner, adapt the layout, etc.

```
/**
 * Hides a spinner's drop down.
 */
public static void hideSpinnerDropDown(Spinner spinner) {
    try {
        Method method = Spinner.class.getDeclaredMethod("onDetachedFromWindow");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(spinner);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- You can popup **Activity** as Dialog Theme.
- Override [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method.

  protected void onPause (){
     super.onPause ();
     this.finish();
   }

Answer (score -3):

spinner.clearFocus();

this is simple line to close spinner programitically