# Android App closes on startup

Tags: android

I've got a problem: when I try to debug my app in my device, it just instantly closes it after launch.

Here's the code:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText convFromET, convToET, commaNumbET;
    Spinner  selectCatS, convFromS, convToS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        convFromET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_convert_from);
        convToET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_convert_to);
        commaNumbET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_comma_numbers);

        selectCatS = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_select_category);
        convFromS = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_convert_from);
        convToS = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_convert_to);

        SetSelectCatSOnClickListener( );


    }

    private void SetSelectCatSOnClickListener( ){
        selectCatS.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

                switch( position ) {
                    case 0: // length
                        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.spinner_length, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                        break;

                    case 1: // speed
                        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.spinner_speed, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
                        break;

                    case 2: //tempreture
                        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.spinner_tempreture, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
                        break;

                    case 3: // volume
                        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( getApplicationContext(), R.array.spinner_volume, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
                        break;

                    default: // Weigth
                        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( getApplicationContext(), R.array.spinner_weigth, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
                        break;
                }

                adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
                convFromS.setAdapter( adapter );
                convToS.setAdapter( adapter );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here's the XML file ( strings.xml ):

```
<string name="select_category">Choose a category</string>
<string name="convert_from">Convert from</string>
<string name="convert_to">Convert to</string>
<string name="numbers_after_comma">Numbers after comma</string>

<string-array name="spinner_categories">
    <item>Length</item>
    <item>Weigth</item>
    <item>Volume</item>
    <item>Tempreture</item>
    <item>Speed</item>
    <item>Volume</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="spinner_length">
    <item>Inches</item>
    <item>Feets</item>
    <item>Centimeters</item>
    <item>Meters</item>
    <item>Kilometers</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="spinner_speed">
    <item>Meters per second</item>
    <item>Kilometers per hour</item>
    <item>Miles per hour</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="spinner_tempreture">
    <item>Celsius</item>
    <item>Farenheith</item>
    <item>Kelvin</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="spinner_volume">
    <item>Cubic milimeters</item>
    <item>Cubic centimeters</item>
    <item>Cubic meters</item>
    <item>Liters</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="spinner_weigth">
    <item>Miligrams</item>
    <item>Grams</item>
    <item>Kilograms</item>
    <item>Pounds</item>
    <item>Tons</item>
</string-array>
```

By the way, when I comment `SetSelectCatSOnClickListener()` in `onCreate`, the app doesn't crash, so I assume that problem must be there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: logs? is selectCatS null when used?

Comment: Umm, any tip on how to filter those logs ? Because I get like milion of entries and I have no clue how to find the right one...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not OnItemClick it should be onItemSelected for the spinner

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem. I've changed that and now my app runs just fine.

Answer (score -1):

To find out specifics on the **error with logcat**.

**On eclipse:**

> *Go to Window -> Show View -> Android -> logcat.*

**Logcat is then pinned to the bottom of you screen.**

You will see a drop down that has **verbose by default**. Change that to error. Now you will only see errors in Logcat.

Once you have the error post it here and I am sure we can help you.

Comment: Another thing, I just read your code. If you are beginner in android. I suggest you extend your Main class to just Activity. Instead of AppCompatActivity, just to avoid unnecessary stuff.

Comment: refer to this post because you cannot use onItemClickListener on a Spinner. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064498/setonitemclicklistener-not-works-with-spinner

Comment: Actually you're wrong. `AppCompatActivity` is a class provided in the latest android support library. Refer to this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity

Comment: I never said it was wrong. Notice I said "If you are a beginner". No need to have a bunch of implemented methods and extra stuff happening when you are just learning the basics.

Comment: Even though he is a beginner, at some point he will need to learn how to use the AppCompat Library, and extending AppCompatActivity doesn't demand any effort on "method implementations and extra stuff". Besides, there isn't any downsides in  learning the right way, huh ?

Comment: Would it be easier to understand what an Activity is, versus a ListActivity, FragmentActivity, etc... . It's always easier to dive in with simplicity to understand the full picture. Either way, most resources (books, online tutorials) extend the Activity class. Ask yourself why they might do that?