# Spinner onClick listener

Tags: java, android

I would like to call an action every time my spinner selects a new item. The current setup is that an action is called when a button is pressed.

My approach:

Create a new function: `public void onSpinnerItemSelection(View V){...}`

Then in `content_home.xml` I would add `onSpinnerItemSelection` to `onClick` for `Spinner`.

This isn't working. I'm not familiar with Android errors and I'm struggling to interpret these errors.

```
Unfortunately, myApp has stopped

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
```

Comment: I would use `onItemSelected` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15064634/2308683

Comment: You should create a CustomView to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:

1ªDeclare variables from the layout`Spinner sp;` the arraylist in this case `ArrayList listTeams;` and the adapter `Adapter adapter;`

2ªinstances

```
private void instances() {

    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    listaTeam = new ArrayList();
```

3º add items for the adapter

```
private void listAdapter() {

    listaTeam.add(new Equipo(R.string.Atleti));
    adaptador = new Adaptador(MainActivity.this, listaEquipo);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

now we make actions, use onItemSelected.

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

```
    Toast.makeText("this is my team", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3W0-Nv664I

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {
        Toast.makeText("log", "position = " position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {
        Toast.makeText("log", "onNothingSelected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```